# CSS selector precedence - why is td higher than a pseudo-selector?

Tags: html, css, operator-precedence

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/czz2ejfw/1

Style for my table:

```
td {
    color: #669;
}
tbody tr:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

The text color *should* be red when we hover.  In fact, if you look at developer tools you see that red should be applied.  But incredibly, it displays as #669.  WTH?

[image]

This is consistent across Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

Comment: Because the style on `td` is more specific to the cell which is actually getting styled. You would notice a difference when the rule is set as `tbody tr:hover td{}`.

Comment: That is a horrible background-text color combination, just saying.

Comment: @DJDavid98 What do you have against hotdog color schemes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't more specific. It matches a different element.

`td { color: #669; }` overrides the default stylesheet (which is probably something like `td { color: inherit; }`) because author stylesheets override browser stylesheets.

If you want to match the `td` when the `tr` is hovered, then you need to mention the `td` in the selector (e.g. with a descendant combinator).

```
tbody tr:hover td {}
```

Comment: True that. I meant to say *specific* as in the there is a very specific value explicitly assigned (to the `td`) which will take priority over the default stylesheet. If the `color` on `td` wasn't there the `tr:hover` itself would have resulted in a red color. But probably a wrong choice of words.

Answer (score 1):

`<tr>` is getting the `color:red;` but there is nothing there to be styled red.

Instead you would need to do this, which applies red to all `<td>` cells that are children of the parent `<tr>`:

```
tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

tbody tr:hover td {
    color: red;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/czz2ejfw/1/)**

Comment: I didn't...I had a slightly different answer which was correct and then I edited it to improve it. My original answer was styling an individual `<td>`, and I adjusted it to style the whole row.

Comment: Your older answer wasn't correct, it changed color of the cell hovered but what Rap wants is to change row color

Comment: You copy it, erased it and claimed it as yours. Everyone here is trying to help, it's unfair to do what you have done, take advantage of somebody else's effort.

Comment: The OP doesn't specify one over another as being more desirable.  I didn't copy anything I edited my answer to make it work better.

Answer (score 1):

As actually already said in a comment, the `td` is a child of the `tr`, so although the background of the `tr` changes, if you can't see it anywhere because none of the `td`'s are transparent you won't get anywhere. The correct solution thus is to either make the `td`'s `transparent` (default) and instead style the `tr`'s always, or use `tr:hover td{}` to override the styles of the `td` instead of styling the `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Update that part of your CSS to this and it will work:

```
tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
tbody tr:hover td{
    color: red;
}
```

Red is higher priority in your version because it is specific for `td` the `tbody tr` is not that specific

Comment: Try not to use the word "specific", because it implies specificity is in play. `tbody tr` has a higher specificity than `td`. Specificity is not the determining factor here.

Comment: Im not sure if you are aware of CSS weights depending on how specific the selector is to the element you want to target. It depends a lot of it.

Comment: tbody tr doesn't have higher specificity than td here. td has it because it targets the element directly

Comment: That's not what [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) is. Specificity is about giving a score to the selector, not which element is the subject.